# Angular6: Serving assets using CDN but not Index.html - SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'

Tags: angular, angular6, cdn

**Goal**

Serve all files excluding index.html on a CDN (CloudFront). Thus the app is served on a subdomain that's different than the assets.

**Problem**

I used `ng build --prod --aot --base-href https://mycdn.x.com` to build my app, and then sent all the files over to my CDN. An nginx server is serving index.html

What happened is that on app load, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': 
A history state object with URL 'https://mycdn.x.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 
'https://myapp.x.com' and URL 'https://myapp.x.com/page1/page2'.
```

**Notes**

- All the files were loaded with 200 code.
- CORS is setup for GET/HEAD with * origin.

How can I serve all assets from a CDN while keeping the app sane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, should've used `--deploy-url` not `--base-href`.

```
ng build --prod --aot --deploy-url https://mycdn.x.com
```